# fn_trace_gettable Error SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, permissions

When I Execute
 `SELECT * FROM FN_TRACE_GETTABLE(N'E:\Trace_Files\trace1.trc', 1)`
It says "You do not have permission to run `'FN_TRACE_GETTABLE"`, What type of permission on server required to execute the above query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Requires [ALTER TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188425(v=sql.100).aspx) permission on the server.

**Note** :- This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server (2014 above). Avoid using this feature in new development work.